# Error 56 - Unable to load the SQLUserInstance.dll > from the location specified in the registry (It's there!)

Tags: sql-server, localdb

I've seen a number of questions that include this error, but none that specifically address the file in the error - SqlUserInstance.dll - or a solution not involving additional software.

### The Scenario

I'm a hobbyist developing a Windows app in VB.NET. It uses SQL Server, and during installation, if the user does not already have a SQL Server instance running, it installs SQL Server 2019 LocalDB. There is no application interface for the database - no SSMS or Visual Studio. The user is asked to approve installation of SQL Server but needs to have 0 knowledge of databases to use the application.

### The Installation

1. My application first checks for the existence of vcruntime140.dll as a proxy to see if the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable package is installed. If the file doesn't exist, the application downloads and installs it:

   ```
    Using client As New WebClient
        client.DownloadFile("https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vc_redist.x64.exe", Path.GetTempPath & "vc_redist.exe")
    End Using
    Dim myProcess As New Process
    myProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = Path.GetTempPath & "vc_redist.exe"
    myProcess.Start()
   ```
2. The application copies SqlLocalDB and its resources to the ProgramData folder and uses it to check if any LocalDB instances 14 or higher exist and return the instance using the highest version of SQL Server.

   ```
    Public Function GetDbDSN_New(installDir As String) As String
        Dim instances = RunProcess(installDir + "\SqlLocalDb", "i")
        Dim maxInstance As String = Nothing
        Dim maxVersion As String = "14.99999.99999.99999"
        For Each instance In instances
            Dim thisInstance As String = ""
            For Each line In RunProcess(installDir + "\SqlLocalDb", "i " + instance)
                If line.StartsWith("Name:") Then
                    thisInstance = LTrim(line.Remove(0, 5))
                End If
                If line.StartsWith("Version:") AndAlso UpdateRequired(maxVersion, line.Remove(0, 9)) Then
                    maxInstance = "(LocalDB)\" + thisInstance
                    maxVersion = line.Remove(0, 9)
                End If
            Next
        Next
        Return maxInstance
    End Function
   ```

If no instance is found, the user is given the opportunity to manually enter one if they know it or a choice to install SQL Server LocalDB.

### The Problem

When trying to connect to the automatic instance MSSQLLOCALDB - on my VM running a clean install of Win10 Home and also on some beta testers computers - I get the error

> "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
> establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
> was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
> SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
> Network Interfaces, error: 56 - Unable to load the SQLUserInstance.dll
> from the location specified in the registry. Verify that the Local
> Database Runtime feature of SQL Server Express is properly
> installed.)"

```
    Try
        Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLOCALDB15;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30")
        conn.Open()
        conn.Close()
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
```

Here's the catch - SqlUserInstance.dll *does* exist in the location specified in the registry.  Here's a screenshot from HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Installed Versions\15.0 which shows that InstanceAPIPath is C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\LocalDB\Binn\SqlUserInstance.dll

[image: Registry Screen Shot]

And here's a screenshot which shows SqlUserInstance.dll in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\LocalDB\Binn

[image]

### The Questions

1. Is the problem really that SQL Server can't find the .dll file in question? And if so why and what can I do about it?
2. Given that many other solutions on SO involve changing settings in SSMS or Visual Studio, how do I fix this from within my own application on a user's computer using the command line and not requiring any knowledge from the user?

Comment: Actually the error message says that it cannot *load* the file in question, which is different than cannot *find* the file in question. Are you sure that all dependencies have been installed correctly? If you can still find the Microsoft Dependency Walker tool (depends.exe) from a reputable source does it warn about any missing static imports?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have installed both the VC_redist.x86.exe and VC_redist.x64.exe For [Visual C++ Runtimes 2015 to 2022](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170#visual-studio-2015-2017-2019-and-2022). You will get errors during the install if you dont have the x64 version installed, but just your error if the x86 redist isnt installed.